# Export content of HTML element to CSV file in JS

Tags: javascript, html, export

I'm trying to put the ​​displayed values in the  tag on a csv file. However when I export, I download an empty file. What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var file;
    var download = document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent;
    download = file;
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile"/>
    <a id="export" download="export.csv" href="data:text/html,">Export</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- preformatted text -->  
    <pre id="fileContents">
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo</pre>
    <!--/preformatted text -->  

    <!-- app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the text content to the `<a>` element, by adding one more line in your script:

```
document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var download = document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent;
    // adds text to <a> element
    this.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(download)); 
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a file to download via a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). To do this, you set the 'href' attribute of the anchor tag to the data URI encoding the file you want to download. If you use a plain text (not base64) URI, be sure and URL-escape the string you are encoding.

```js
document.getElementById("export").addEventListener("click",function(){
    let dataUri = 'data:text/html,' 
        + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent);
    this.href = dataUri;        
},false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile"/>
    <a id="export" download="export.csv" href="data:text/html,">Export</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- preformatted text -->  
    <pre id="fileContents">
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo
    ojdaoj,feokokfe,dawff,efofewfo</pre>
    <!--/preformatted text -->  

    <!-- app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```